# what is ('/tmp/text8') gensim

Tags: python, gensim

I am implementing the tutorial of gensim http://rare-technologies.com/deep-learning-with-word2vec-and-gensim/ that includes the line 
    sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus('/tmp/text8')
however when I run the program I get the error that text8 does not exist. Looking through the code I see that Text8Corpus is a method that accepts argument type object. The instructions indicate that it should be passed

http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip

When I manually download this file and attempt to pass the resulting imbd uncompressed data set I am told that permissions denied. Does anyone have any insight into this problem ? Am I suppose to have downloaded the imdb dataset myself or was there suppose to be some pointers in the code that do it automatically ?

Comment: Are you on windows/linux/osx/other? Looks to me like you need to unzip the text8.zip in the `/tmp/` folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like he says in his description, you need to download and unzip the file to /tmp directory. you can do this like this:

```
 wget http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip -P /tmp
 unzip text8.zip
```

Now you should be ok ;)

Comment: thing is , I did download the file and upzip it, but got permission issues. wget that does not seem to work on windows

Comment: ok, i thought you were on linux, then you can simply tap %tmp% in your windows search and copy the file there. If you have permission issues try to change the file to another directory and update the code .